# C# byte array problem

Tags: c#, string, binary

I found this code snippet on a blog as a  **"Convert Binary data to text"**

```
Byte[] arrByte = {0,0,0,1,0,1};

string x = Convert.ToBase64String(arrByte);
System: Console.WriteLine(x);
```

And this provides a output of `AAAAAQAB`  ..

What is not clear is that how `000101` -> is mapped to `AAAAAQAB`, and will I able to use this to all `a-z` characters as a binary equivalent and how? or is there a any other method ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The base 64 algorithm is easy to find (and equally easy to undestand in my opinion). See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001` is mapped to `AAAAAQAB` because base64 uses 6 bits per letter so:

```
000000 = A (0)
000000 = A
000000 = A
000000 = A
000000 = A
010000 = Q  (16)
000000 = A
000001 = B  (1)
```

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more details.

Comment: +1 Nicey illustrates what the problem the OP had. That an array of bytes is not an array of bits

Comment: hi thanks for the answer my other problem is how other characters can be mapped in here ? thats the thing i dont get :-)

Comment: @sudantha I don't understand your second question. Can you explain?

Comment: Richard if A is `000000` (0) what C will be ? what will Z will be lyc that ?

Comment: Did you take a peek at that Wikipedia article? It has a very nicely laid out table that shows which value goes with which letter, uppercase and lowercase. C=3 and Z=25.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using, `ToBase64String` is the following. ([from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64))

> Base64 is a group of similar encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation. The Base64 term originates from a specific MIME content transfer encoding.

To use a `string` as a `byte[]` or the other way you can use `Encoding`

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

So

```
72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100
```

is equals to

```
Hello World
```

To bytes and from bytes:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world");
var str   = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```